# numpy with OpenBLAS slower than blas/lapack

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, lapack, blas, openblas

I wanted to install openBLAS on my linux mint 17.2 to speed up some computations. I followed this tutorial [[1]](https://hunseblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/installing-numpy-and-openblas/comment-page-1/#comment-51) and successfully installed openBLAS and numpy (I used 1.9.3 version). I run the test program and got the following results:

```
dotted two (1000,1000) matrices in 167.9 ms
dotted two (4000) vectors in 6.85 us
SVD of (2000,1000) matrix in 2.860 s
Eigendecomp of (1500,1500) matrix in 26.969 s
```

Actually, when I removed numpy and installed system numpy with sudo apt-get install python-numpy I got the following resutls:

```
dotted two (1000,1000) matrices in 255.2 ms
dotted two (4000) vectors in 5.77 us
SVD of (2000,1000) matrix in 3.476 s
Eigendecomp of (1500,1500) matrix in 13.271 s
```

It seems that openblas routines are slower than native blas and lapack. What might be wrong?

This is numpy.show_config() output:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/openblas/lib']
    language = f77
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/openblas/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/openblas/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/openblas/lib']
    language = f77
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

My processor have 4 CPUs with 2 threads per core. I checked with htop that 5-6 threads were present when running test example.

Comment: A single timing doesn't say much.. you should use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to do proper benchmarking. If you have IPython it can be done with `%timeit my_function()`

Comment: Noob OT question? What would be the "native blas and lapack" in this case? The GNU versions. The ones at netlib? Something else?

Comment: I have the same phenomenon with R.